# If something is already happening then cancel

Tags: swift, xcode

I have several timers in my app. I want the "main" timer to start, whenever I start another timer. So no matter what Timer I start the "main" timer also starts. The problem is just when I then press the other timers, it multiplies the "main" timer so it goes a lot faster. Can anyone help, please :-)

The startbutton is the "main" timer

```
@IBAction func hasStartButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    startButton.isHidden = true
    pauseButton.isHidden = false
    stopButton.isEnabled = true

    stopWatchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.updateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@IBAction func hasHomeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    homePossesion = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.homeupdateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    stopWatchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.updateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func hasAwayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    awayPossesion = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.awayupdateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    stopWatchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.updateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@IBAction func hasNeutralButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    neutralPossesion = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.neutralupdateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    stopWatchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.updateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private var stopWatchTimer: Timer? = nil {
    willSet {
        stopWatchTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}

private func startStopWatch() {
    if stopWatchTimer == nil {
        stopWatchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(gameViewController.updateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } // else already running
}

private func stopStopWatch() {
    stopWatchTimer = nil
}

@IBAction func hasStartButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    startButton.isHidden = true
    pauseButton.isHidden = false
    stopButton.isEnabled = true

    startStopWatch()
}
```